# How to create a PDF file from html using PHP then send it to predefined email?

Tags: php, html, email

I want a simple html page that takes:

Name - user's time and date and set them in a single paged pdf then send it to a predefined email.

I am a newbie in php can you give me a simple example please?

Comment: Hi Majd Salim, you'll need to do a few things to your question to get the best replys: 1) Write the question in full, define your vague "Name - users time and date", 2) what have you tried? 3) what other requirements are there? which data is static and which data is dynamic? What is the HTML page for? the PHP does the work, not the HTML page, that is simply a result or output, you see, your question will need to be a little juggled to encourage those who know to bother sharing. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need external library. Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), this pretty much give a good explanation on how to install and how to use the library.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php) is a good example

Use `PDF_set_info` to set information about the PDF and `PDF_show` for the actual content. Then if you wish to send it by email use the `mail()`function, [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) is a great library for creating PDF Files. It is open-source (always a plus) and good for creating simple to complex PDF layouts.

You can also check out [HTML2FPDF](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/) on sourceforge.

Comment: Links to Tutorials :  http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php
Link to Scripts: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php